# Ninject Func clarification

Tags: c#

Could someone please help me to understand the statement below please:

```
kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => ctx.Kernel)
```

1. What does above code do?
2. What is Func?
3. Is it trying to bind and Interface IKernel to something...? This part really confuses me:
   `<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => ctx.Kernel`)

I'm aware that kernel.bind is used to bind the Interface to Concrete type but not sure about the above as there's no concrete type given.

How does it fits in to the real world scenario. Basically why and when do I use this function

Thanks

Comment: BTW: this has nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: FYI, this isn't a Linq query. The `ToMethod` method takes a `Func<IContext, T>` where `T` is the return type. The code `ctx => () => ctx.Kernal` is a Lambda expression (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) which can be cast to a `Func<IContext, T>`. Lambdas are often used with the Linq operators but the code you posted isn't a Linq query.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).

Basically it tells the `DIContainer` of ninject to return a function returning the `Kernel` of the current context whenever somethings asks the `DIContainer` for a `Func<IKernel>`.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject).

---

So, what is `Func`?

From [the documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx):

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the TResult parameter.

You should have a look into [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, but still unclear on what is Func<IKernel> and ctx.Kernal  Is it possible to explain in simple term.

Comment: `Func<IKernel>` is a generic type, and `ctx => () => ctx.Kernel` is a lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks what does this do?ctx => () => ctx.Kernel

Comment: Basically it creates a new method with one parameter of type `IContext` and return type `IKernel`. This method will, when called, return the `Kernel` property of the object passed as parameter.

Comment: still unclear sorry. At what point in time IContext comes in? How does it fits in to the real world scenario. Basically why and when do I use this function.

Comment: You should read about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).